# WPF Popup - hide only on mouse leave the control and the popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have simple border control with `MouseEnter` event which opens popup control. The popup is mush bigger than the border, so it goes beyond the bounds of the border. The popup also has some buttons and textblocks, so I need to take some control on it. Now, what I want to obtain: Mouse enters the border - the popup shows up. Mouse leaves the border AND the popup - then the popup closes. So, when mouse is not over the border but is over the popup - the popup stays open. I don't want to close on click. Can you help me? Popup control in WPF is confusing for me.

Edit:
Right, the code:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Popup PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupBorder}" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="True" x:Name="DeviceStatusSnippetPopup">
        <Border Background="White" Padding="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Device status snippet" Margin="0 10 0 10"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource btn-default}" Margin="0 0 5 0" Content="Go to device"/>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource btn-default}" Content="Refresh device"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
    <Border x:Name="OpenPopupBorder" Width="90" Height="30" Background="LightGray" MouseEnter="Border_MouseEnter"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DeviceStatusSnippetPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: will you share some of your code here?

Comment: Just set triggers for your `popup` for `IsMouseOver` property, if `IsMouseOver== true` then in setter `popup.IsOpen=true`, and second `IsMouseOver==false` => `popup.IsOpen=false`. It really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DeviceStatusSnippetPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void Popup_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!OpenPopupBorder.IsMouseOver)
            DeviceStatusSnippetPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }


    private void Border_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!DeviceStatusSnippetPopup.IsMouseOver)
            DeviceStatusSnippetPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

XAML (minus Window):

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Popup MouseLeave="Popup_MouseLeave" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupBorder}" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="True" x:Name="DeviceStatusSnippetPopup">
        <Border Background="White" Padding="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Device status snippet" Margin="0 10 0 10"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Margin="0 0 5 0" Content="Go to device"/>
                        <Button Content="Refresh device"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
    <Border x:Name="OpenPopupBorder" Width="90" Height="30" Background="LightGray" MouseEnter="Border_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Border_MouseLeave"/>
</Grid>
```

Basically, you implement an event handler for MouseLeave for both the border and the popup, and check in each if the mouse is over the other before closing the popup.

Comment: This is the solution! Thanks!